# Using a bloc with Navigator 2.0

Tags: flutter

Hi I am trying to use a bloc instead of ChangeNotifierDelegate in my RouterDelegate class. Unfortunately the bloc is not being called when a route is changed through my routebloc, not sure why. I have tried wrapping the delegate in a BlocProvider, but it made no difference (I currently have it injected above in the main file.)

```
runApp(MyApp());


class _MyApp AppState extends State<MyApp> {
  MyAppRouterDelegate _routerDelegate = MyAppRouterDelegate();
  MyAppRouteInformationParser _routeInformationParser = MyAppRouteInformationParser();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiBlocProvider(
      providers: [
        BlocProvider(
          lazy: false,
          create: (context) => getIt<AuthBloc>()//..add(AppStarted()),
        ),
        BlocProvider(
          lazy: false,
          create: (context) => getIt<RouterBloc>(),
        ),
      ],
      child: MaterialApp.router(
      title: 'MyApp',
      theme: globalAppThemeData,
      routerDelegate: _routerDelegate,
      routeInformationParser: _routeInformationParser,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

In my RouterDelegate I have .....

```
lass MyAppRouterDelegate extends RouterDelegate<MyAppConfiguration>
    with ChangeNotifier, PopNavigatorRouterDelegateMixin<MyAppConfiguration> {
  final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> _navigatorKey;
  String currentPage = '';
  String selectedItem = '';

  @override
  GlobalKey<NavigatorState> get navigatorKey => _navigatorKey;

  MyAppRouterDelegate() : _navigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();

  @override
  MyAppConfiguration get currentConfiguration {
    currentPage = currentConfiguration.screen;
    selectedItem = currentConfiguration.selectedItemId;
    if (currentPage == UNKNOWN) {
      return MyAppConfiguration.unknown();
    } else if (currentPage == SPLASH) {
      return MyAppConfiguration.splash();
    } else if (currentPage == LOGIN) {
      return MyAppConfiguration.login();
    } else {
      return MyAppConfiguration.unknown();
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<Page> pages = [SplashPage(SPLASH)];
    return BlocBuilder<RouterBloc, RouterState>(
      builder: (context, state) {
        if (state is ChangedRoute) {
          pages.clear();
          pages = state.pages;
        }
        return Navigator(
          key: navigatorKey,
          pages: pages,
          onPopPage: (route, result) {
            if (!route.didPop(result)) return false;
            context.read<AuthBloc>().add(AuthEventLoggedOut());
            return true;
          },
        );
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Future<void> setNewRoutePath(MyAppConfiguration configuration) async {
    if (configuration.unknown) {
      currentPage = UNKNOWN;
      selectedItem = configuration.selectedItemId;
    } else if (configuration.isSplashPage) {
      currentPage = SPLASH;
      selectedItem = configuration.selectedItemId;
    } else if (configuration.isLoginPage) {
      currentPage = LOGIN;
      selectedItem = configuration.selectedItemId;
    } else if (configuration.isSignUpPage) 
      currentPage = SIGNUP;
      selectedItem = configuration.selectedItemId;
    } else {
      print(Constants.failureCouldNotSetRoute);
    }
  }

  _clear() {
    currentPage = UNKNOWN;
    selectedItem = '';
  }
}
```

In my app configuration...

```
class MyAppInformationParser
    extends RouteInformationParser<MyAppConfiguration> {

  @override
  Future<MyAppConfiguration> parseRouteInformation(RouteInformation? routeInformation) async {
    final uri = Uri.parse(routeInformation!.location!);
    if (uri.pathSegments.length == 0) {
      return MyAppConfiguration.splash();
    } else if (uri.pathSegments.length == 1) {
      final first = uri.pathSegments[1].toLowerCase();
      if (first == LOGIN) {
        return MyAppConfiguration.login();
    } else {
        return MyAppConfiguration.unknown();
      }
    } else {
      return MyAppConfiguration.unknown();
    }
  }

  @override
  RouteInformation restoreRouteInformation(MyAppConfiguration configuration) {
    if (configuration.isUnknownPage) {
      return RouteInformation(location: '/unknown');
    } else if (configuration.isSplashPage) {
      return RouteInformation(location: '/splash');
    } else if (configuration.isLoginPage) {
      return RouteInformation(location: '/login');
    } else {
      return RouteInformation(location: '/unknown');
    }
  }
}
```

My auth bloc ...

```
@injectable
class AuthBloc extends Bloc<AuthEvent, AuthState> {
  IAuthFacade authRepo;
  RouterBloc routerBloc;

  AuthBloc(this.authRepo, this.routerBloc) : super(Uninitialized());

  @override
  Stream<AuthState> mapEventToState(
    AuthEvent event,
  ) async* {
    if (event is AppStarted) {
      yield AuthenticationLoading();
      Option<CurrentUser> user = await authRepo.getSignedInUser();
      yield user.fold(() {
        routerBloc.add(RouterEventNewPage(pages: [LoginPage(LOGIN)]));
        return Unauthenticated();
      }, (user) {
        routerBloc.add(RouterEventNewPage(pages: [HomePage(HOME)]));
        return Authenticated(user);
      });
    }

    if (event is AuthEventLoggedOut) {
      authRepo.signOut();

      ///TODO: clear hive here??
    }
  }
}

abstract class AuthEvent extends Equatable {

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [];

}

//
class AppStarted extends AuthEvent {}

//
class AuthEventLoggedOut extends AuthEvent {}


abstract class AuthState extends Equatable {

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [];

}

//
class Uninitialized extends AuthState {}

//
class Authenticated extends AuthState {
  final CurrentUser user;
  Authenticated(this.user);
}

//
class Unauthenticated extends AuthState {}

//
class AuthenticationLoading extends AuthState {}
```

My Router Bloc...

```
@injectable
class RouterBloc extends Bloc<RouterEvent, RouterState> {
  RouterBloc() : super(RouterInitial());

  @override
  Stream<RouterState> mapEventToState(
    RouterEvent event,
  ) async* {
    if (event is RouterEventNewPage) {
      yield ChangingRoute();
      yield ChangedRoute(pages: event.pages);
    }
  }
}

abstract class RouterEvent extends Equatable {
  const RouterEvent();

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [];
}

class RouterEventNewPage extends RouterEvent {
  final List<Page> pages;

  RouterEventNewPage({required this.pages});

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [pages];
}



abstract class RouterState extends Equatable {
  const RouterState();
  
  @override
  List<Object> get props => [];
}

class RouterInitial extends RouterState {}

class ChangingRoute extends RouterState {}

class ChangedRoute extends RouterState {

  final List<Page> pages;

  ChangedRoute({required this.pages});

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [pages];
}
```

The app runs through the Navigator in the build function of the delegate first, it navigates to the splash screen perfectly, then after my animation finishes in the splash screen it calls the auth bloc to check if user is authorised, this works perfectly which then calls the routerbloc. The router bloc adds the new login screen (as the user is logged out). However, the bloc inside the build function of the MyAppRouterDelegate is not firing again.

Any help provided would be very much appreciated.

When it runs through the MyAppRouterDelegates build function the first time I do receive the error

"
════════ Exception caught by scheduler library ═════════════════════════════════
The following StackOverflowError was thrown during a scheduler callback:
Stack Overflow

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack
#0      CrokettRouterDelegate.currentConfiguration
package:crokett/routes/crokett_router_delegate.dart:20
"

But I don't receive any more information on the error.

Answer (score 1):

Don't you need a notifyListeners() somewhere in your blocBuilder after you update the page stack?
I am interested to know if you got it working.

Comment: Hi sorry, just seen your comment. I did try removing the notifyListeners(). However I could not get it to work in the end. So I ended up just removing the routerBloc and now I just put a function callback in every PageViewClass to trigger the navigation. Not quite as clean but it works, so I am able to use this nav for my website as well. Thx for your response.